# Create a method which matches a reflected type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates, codedom

I am utilising a 3rd party .net dll, which I am making calls to. I am simplifying my code, but it's something like this.

```
// The assembly has already been loaded into 'ass'

Type params = ass.GetType("RemoteCalls.ParametersDelegate");
Delegate UseDel = Delegate.CreateDelegate(params, this, "MyGetParams");
```

I can then pass this delegate (UseDel) into the reflected object, and it will call MyGetParams when it needs to.

The problem I'm having is that the method signature is made up of a type within the 3rd party dll.

The signature of the ParametersDelegate is...

```
Parameters GetPars();
```

So, my method can't return the correct type (Parameters). I have tried the following..

```
private static class OtherDelegates<T>
{
    public static T MyGetParams()
    {
        //... code to build up the 'Parameters' class, and return it.
    }
}
```

Then calling..

```
Delegate UseDel = Delegate.CreateDelegate(params, this, "OtherDelegates<xxx>.MyGetParams");
```

But I can't work out what to put in 'xxx'.

I think that I might be able to do this by using **CodeDomProvider** , but wondered if there is a simpler way ?

Also, it's not an option to add the DLL as a reference due to licensing issues.

Thanks 
Rich.

Comment: If the licensing issues affect you *as a reference*, then I can't see how those same licensing issues magically *don't* affect you by using reflection. Can you be more specific? this sounds very very dubious reasoning...

Comment: I want my software to be able to utilise this DLL if it's installed/avilable, I don't want it to be dependant upon it. Also, from a development point of view, I don't want to have to install this third party dll onto all development machines. Anyway, I'd rather get around the coding issue, rather than the licensing issue.

Comment: Also, we only have a limited number of licences for the 3rd party software, so I can't release it with every installation of our main software.

Comment: having done similar things before, I suggest hiding the external dll behind a library dll of your own (that references the 3rd party dll), WITHOUT EXPOSING any of the 3rd party types on the API. You main app code then references your wrapper, and it all just works. You obviously need to code defensively (handling exceptions if the 3rd party lib isn't there), but you need that *anyway* in your example. It just avoids all this reflection mess!

Comment: Yep, that's a good solution. Do you mind if I leave this question open, just to see if there is a way of doing this through code ? I'm also quite keen to understand (without getting bogged down in it) the complexities of reflection / delegates etc..

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell, do you want to add your comment as an answer, then I can accept it (if that's the way things work around here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would completely encapsulate the third party dll behind a library dll that you control, using **none** of the 3rd-party types on the interface. This means you can reference your (already built) library dll in isolation. Obviously you still need to code in sch a way that it fails gracefully when the 3rd party dll is not available.

This also has side benefits:

- you can mock the implemetation for testing
- you can provide a fallback strategy the 3rd party dll isn't there
- you can potentially support multiple providers

I've used the above very successfully, for example wrapping MapPoint (geo-routing) with a great-arc fallback.

Plus - you don't need to mess around with the reflection!